# Using generics with custom object in method parameters

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have 2 classes as below ::

```
ItemA {
    // varibales and methods.
}

ItemB{
    // varibales and methods.
}
```

And I have a method in a service class :

```
public Map<String, ItemDetails> getItemDetails(Map<String, ItemA> itemMap, String itemType){

    // do something

}
```

Now I need to pass ItemA or ItemB based upon some conditions in the caller. The return type doesn't change in either case. How I can do that using generics or wild cards.

This is what I am trying to achieve :

```
public Map<String, ItemDetails> getItemDetails(Map<String, ?> itemMap, String itemType){

    // do something

}
```

Is the above a good way to handle the scenario or please suggest a better approach. I am new to generics so need your kind help.

Comment: Do `ItemA` and `ItemB` descend from the same class or implement the same interface? And, more importantly, do you need to do something with `itemMap`'s values?

Comment: How are you going to extract the result `Map`'s keys? This is not enough info to suggest something useful.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  They do not implement any class. They are my model classes. And yes I am looping through the itemMap values with itemMap.entrySet().

Comment: @Som my point being, if you don't need to call methods on the values inside the `getItemDetails` method your solution is sufficient (because the method doesn't really care what the type of the value is). Otherwise see the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a combination of Polymorphism and Generics could be the way to go.

Consider having an interface `Item` and change your classes correspondingly

```
interface Item {
    // TODO: declare methods common for all items
}


class ItemA implements Item {
    // TODO: implement the interface
}

class ItemB implements Item {
    // TODO: implement the interface
}
```

Then your method would become

```
public Map<String, ItemDetails> getItemDetails(Map<String, Item> items) {
   // TODO: implement the method body
}
```

But beware writing conditions based on the class types, [as it's a common anti pattern](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

i.e. it's better avoid code like this

```
// anti pattern, should be avoided
if (item instanceof ItemA) {
    // do one thing
} else if (item instanceof ItemB) {
    // do another thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an interface `Item` that both `ItemA` and `ItemB` implement and define your map as `Map<String, Item>`, if that would be appropriate for your use case.